# Boundedness needed to prove the sup metric

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

Let  be the set of all continuous functions from [0,1] into ℝ. For ,∈, define

(,)=sup∈[0,1]|()−()|

For d to be a metric we need continuity so that we have boundedness. But why?

Comment: If you don’t require the functions to be bounded, $d(f,g)$ need not even be finite.

Comment: Boundedness of the functions? Of the interval? It is unclear what you are asking for.

Comment: I just need an example that shows this isn't a metric if it is not bounded

Answer (score 2):

Recall that a metric on a set $X$ is a function $d:X\times X\rightarrow \mathbb{R}$, i.e., it assigns a real number to every pair of elements $f,g\in X$.

Let $X=C^{0}(\mathbb{R},\mathbb{R})$. Consider $f(x) = x$ and $g(x) = 0$. Then $d(f,g)=\sup _{x\in \mathbb{R}}|f(x)-g(x)|=\infty$. So $d$ isn't a metric on $X$.

Comment: I am confused? What does this show? What is $C^{0}(\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$? is it unbounded? Why does $d(f,g)= \infty$ show d is not a metric?

Comment: So $C^{0} (\mathbb{R}, \mathbb{R})$ is the set of continuous functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$. The only restriction im changing from your example is that now functions don't have to be bounded (if I took a compact set like $[0,1]$ then every continuous function would be bounded by the extreme value theorem).

Comment: $\infty$ isn't a real number. This is short for saying the map $d$ can't give a real number to this pair of functions. So it can't be a metric.

Comment: Thank you! It makes since now!